# django allauth reference social account

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth

I'm new to Django, and I'm trying to build an app where a user can post a "trip" (while logged in with django-allauth, facebook social account) and I want that trip model to be tied into the social account of the user whom created it.

I'm having problems saving the trip to the database. I've had to modified the inputted data with Javascript so I'm using an ajax POST request, and I grab the user's social id with `<p class="social-id">{{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.uid }}</p>`

My model is:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    driver = models.OneToOneField(allauth.socialaccount.models.SocialAccount)
```

and I get an error that says: `Cannot assign "'10206730564687878'": "Trip.driver" must be a "SocialAccount" instance.`I tried making the model driver field reference the `allauth.socialaccount.models.SocialAccount.uid` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `OneToOneField`. Can every user only post one trip? If you want them to be able to post more than one, you should use a `ForeignKey()` instead.

Also, is there a reason you are linking it to the `SocialAccount` instance, instead of to the main `User` instance? I would use

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE, related_name='trips')
```

---

Now, the reason you are getting the error is, because you are trying to assign a `str` (text string) to the `OneToOneField` field. But that field expects an instance of `SocialAccount`.

To fix it, instead of doing `trip.driver = "10206730564687878"`, you would need to fetch an instance of `SocialAccount` (for example for the current user) and then assign that to the driver:

```
soc_acc = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=request.user)
trip.driver = soc_acc
trip.save()
```

That would give a `SocialAccount` instance to `trip.driver`.

---

And another thing: if it is the logged in user who adds himself, there is no need to send any `SocialAccount` ID with the form. Rather, get it from `request.user` object of the logged in user.

Comment: thank you! Yes, the OneToOne field is intentional, I only what a user to be able to post one trip